# Binding class to a boolean test in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a series of buttons (using vue-mdl) which act like a tab switcher, so there is the concept of the 'current' tab in view. I'd like to bind a class to the button which is 'active', but I haven't found a way of doing it without using a computed property. The computed property is trivial, and really just needs to compare the button id with the `currentView` data value. So far I've got this:

```
<mdl-button id="accepted"   :class="{activeTab: isAccepted}">Accepted</mdl-button>
<mdl-button id="rejected"   :class="{activeTab: isRejected}">Rejected</mdl-button>
<mdl-button id="training"   :class="{activeTab: isTraining}">Training</mdl-button>
<mdl-button id="config"     :class="{activeTab: isConfig}">Configuration</mdl-button>
<mdl-button id="newsletter" :class="{activeTab: isNewsletter}">Newsletter</mdl-button>

// Computed properties
computed: {
  isAccepted: function () {
    return this.currentView == 'accepted'
  },
  isRejected: function () {
    return this.currentView == 'rejected'
  },
  isTraining: function () {
    return this.currentView == 'training'
  },
  isConfig: function () {
    return this.currentView == 'config'
  },
  isNewsletter: function () {
    return this.currentView == 'newsletter'
  }
}
```

but I don't like it for various reasons - the button ids are in 2 places, lots of repetition of basically the same function, using a function at all, etc. Really, I'd like to write something like this:

```
<mdl-button id="accepted" :class="{activeTab: id == this.currentView}">Accepted</mdl-button>
```

but that's not valid Vue markup. Is there a way to do this without creating a function per button just to do the comparison?

Comment: Why do you have that ID on the button?

Comment: The id is there so all the buttons can use the same click handler, and it knows via e.target.id which 'tab' should become active

Comment: `:class="{activeTab: 'accepted' == currentView}"` should be fine, but you'll have to at least repeat `'accepted'`. (`this` is automatically added when evaling code in template markup)

Comment: Yeah, it's not very DRY to have the same label twice, which is why I'd like to refer to `id` there instead of another literal string. In the end, I went back to having an array and a v-for loop as per the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what loops are for. Use the `v-for` directive:

```html
<mdl-button v-for="tab in tabs"
            :class="{ activeTab: currentView == tab }"
            :id="tab"
>{{ tab | capitalize }}</mdl-button>
```

Then simply add the `capitalize` filter to your parent component:

```js
{
    data () {
        return {
            tabs: [
                'accepted',
                'rejected',
                'training',
                'config',
                'newsletter',
            ]
        };
    },
    filters: {
        capitalize (value) {
            return value[0].toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/xLxzwLo0/

Comment: Annoyingly, I did have this setup originally. But since the tabs are fixed, I preferred to put them in the HTML area only. Seems this is a neater solution than multiple computed properties though. I'll go back to that.